# Access javac options within AnnotationProcessor

Tags: java, javac, annotation-processing

I'm writing custom AnnotationProcessor and need to access options which was set to javac during execution: e.g. -verbose, -s, -d

What is the correct way to do this. I don't think that parsing "sun.java.command" system property or accessing com.sun.tools.javac.util.Options are good way to do this.

Thanks a lot.

PS: May be something like this for -s option:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
StandardJavaFileManager fm = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
Iterable<? extends File> locations = fm.getLocation(StandardLocation.SOURCE_OUTPUT);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** public API to do this. The effect of the "-s" and "-d" options should be reflected in the Filer's behavior and not something a processor needs to directly examine.

Processor-specific options can be passed use "-Afoo=bar", which can be queried from the getOptions method.